# React Native - React Navigation TapBar Action Button stays visible [Myfitnesspal look alike]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to accomplish that the action button stays visible all the time. Once the user tabs on it, a modal appears and of course, the action button stays behind the modal.
I tried:

- Using Portals
- Create another button inside the modal (independent as the original one) but this causes problems depending on the device, and the user can see the transition from one button to another.
- tried this pre-made one but can't seem to put it on tabbar correctly:[actionbutton](https://github.com/geremih/react-native-circular-action-menu)

[image: myfitnesspal example]

**My approach**
[image: qoomit]

**MY CODE**

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import TabBg from '../svg/TabBg';
import colors from './../utils/colors';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
Platform.OS == 'ios'
  ? console.log('ios HEIGHT: ' + height + ' WIDTH: ' + width)
  : console.log('android HEIGHT: ' + height + ' WIDTH: ' + width);

Ionicons.loadFont();
Feather.loadFont();
AntDesign.loadFont();
Entypo.loadFont();
MaterialIcons.loadFont();

const TabBarAdvancedButton = ({bgColor, ...props}) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container} pointerEvents="box-none">
        <TabBg color={'white'} style={styles.background} />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={props.onPress}
          activeOpacity={0.9}
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
          <Entypo name="plus" style={styles.buttonIcon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Modal
        backdropOpacity={0.8}
        animationIn="fadeIn"
        animationOut="fadeOut"
        isVisible={modalVisible}
        onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
        style={styles.contentView}>
        {/*close button */}

        <View style={styles.content}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              backgroundColor: 'red',
              alignSelf: 'center',
            }}>
            <AntDesign name="search1" size={20} color="#fff" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'space-around',
              marginBottom: height * 0.02,
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.buttonItem}>
              <AntDesign name="search1" size={20} color="#fff" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={[styles.buttonItem]}>
              <MaterialIcons name="fitness-center" size={20} color="#fff" />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.buttonItem}>
              <AntDesign name="search1" size={20} color="#fff" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default TabBarAdvancedButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: 75,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  background: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
  },
  button: {
    top: -22.5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 27,
    backgroundColor: colors.PRIMARY_COLOR_DARK,
  },
  buttonIcon: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#F6F7EB',
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    padding: 60,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderTopRightRadius: 17,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 17,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  contentTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  contentView: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    margin: 0,
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 100,
  },
  buttonStyle2: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 100,
  },

  buttonItem: {
    height: 56,
    width: 56,
    borderRadius: 100,
    borderColor: '#468CFF',
    borderWidth: 3.5,
    backgroundColor: '#366ABF',
    bottom: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: You can't build this with a `Modal`-Component. The `Modal`-Component will absolutely always overlay the whole content. You need to "re-structure" your components hierarchy.
Basically, you have at least three layers:
1. Content
2. NavigationBar
(optional layer here just for the presentation of the overlay with the buttons)
3. Plus Button, probably positioned with `absolute`.
When you click on the Plus Button in the third layer you need to open a layer beneath an overlay with the buttons (just a simply view with SCREEN_HEIGHT).
This is the only way I can imagine of how this could work.

Comment: @hannojg any way you can help me doing it?